# Is non-blocking CAS in Java really non-blocking?

Tags: java, concurrency, nonblocking, compare-and-swap

I was going over an article on non-blocking CAS and came across this code:

```
public class SimulatedCAS {
  private int value;

  public synchronized int getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public synchronized int compareAndSwap(int expectedValue, int newValue) {
     int oldValue = value;
     if (value == expectedValue)
         value = newValue;
     return oldValue;
  }
}
```

How is this CAS operation non-blocking if it uses synchronization?

If we mean the client of this `SimulatedCAS` need not implement synchronization of its own, then haven't we just moved the blocking around instead of eliminating it?

Comment: How is this "non-blocking?" Both methods are `synchronized`, which means that two calls cannot happen simultaneously.

Comment: Can you post a link to the article?

Comment: The original source seems to be "Java Concurrency In Practice", page 322 (15.2.1)

Comment: Your example is blocking and does not use real CAS operations.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp04186/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this is a **simulated** CAS (as the name itself implies); in words of Brian Goetz *(the listing comes from his "Java Concurrency In Practice" book)*:

> `SimulatedCAS` in Listing 15.1 illustrates the semantics (but not the implementation or performance) of CAS.

Actual implementation of CAS needs CPU support, classes from the `java.util.concurrent.atomic` package call `native` methods.